# Grid View Items contents in xaml (windows store app)

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps

how can I get to the contents of the clicked grid Item in a grid view ... for example the grid item has a textbox ... how could I get the contents of this textbox when the gridview Item is clicked vie ItemClickEventArgs ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<GridView x:Name="gv" SelectionChanged="gvSelectionChanged">
    <GridViewItem>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtOne" />
    </GridViewItem>
    <GridViewItem>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtTwo" />
    </GridViewItem>
</GridView>

private void gvSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var SelectedText = ((TextBox)((GridViewItem)gv.SelectedItem).Content).Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using ItemsSource with your GridView, you can use e.ClickedItem to get the DataContext of the GridViewItem you clicked. If you want the actual GridViewItem you can use

```
GridViewItem item = (sender as GridView).ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem) as GridViewItem;
```

Then you can use VisualTreeHelper.GetChild to dig down as necessary (like to find a TextBox).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a DataTemplate to display the items in the GridView, I have found the simplest way is to capture Tapped, Hold, etc.. event on the DataTemplate's control that holds all the item.

In the event you can code

```
private void ItemTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    var clickedItem = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
}
```

That will give you the object within the item that was clicked.